# Description card on hover element - what mixture of CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm essentially trying to click on profile pictures and have a card show up with a description below each profile picture. Here is a mock-up of what I am attempting. I have tried several things (using the global on-click JavaScript functionality) but I am struggling to format correctly.

What approach would you take to implement something like this:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I suggest you add the code you have tried to your question, this will help to insure that someone can recreate your issue and help out.